# jquery printing json object using .each shows more results than expected

Tags: jquery, json

There is some error in the code below. The `rJSON` object contains a single `sURL` and single `iURL`(as found by checking in the console.log).
But when the `imgList` displays after the `each` condition, it has 3 identical `sURL` and `iURLs` in it.

Do you see any issues with this code below?

```
C.forgotIt = function (page, rJSON) {
    var tempPage = page;
    var imgList = "";

    $.each(rJSON, function (index, value) {
        imgList += "<a href='" + rJSON.sURLS + "'><img class='hsImage' src='" + rJSON.iURLS + "' /></a>";
    });

    page.find('.hsImages').html("<div class='imgListCont'>" + imgList + "</div>");
};
```

EDIT: rJSON looks like this through console: 
{iURLS: Array[1], sURLS: Array[1], RESULT: "OTHER_MEMBER"}

UPDATE: Currently it has one set of iURLS and sURLS but it could display any number of iURLS(and the same number of sURLS)

Comment: They definitely should be duplicates since you are appending the same content to each anchor tag. the $.each is going through each property of `rJSON` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely rJSON is an object with 3 properties. I already know there are at least 2 properties, `sURLS` and `iURLS`, and since it's iterating three times, there must be a 3rd unused property. (confirmed by edit to OP)

To get your current code to work, you don't need the $.each at all because you don't have an array.

```
 C.forgotIt = function (page, rJSON) {
     var tempPage = page;
     var imgList = "<a href='" + rJSON.sURLS + "'><img class='hsImage' src='" + rJSON.iURLS + "' /></a>";
     page.find('.hsImages').html("<div class='imgListCont'>" + imgList + "</div>");
 };
```

Update for your edit:

you need to use $.each on each property since the properties contain arrays.

```
 C.forgotIt = function (page, rJSON) {
     var tempPage = page;
     var imgList = "";
     $.each(rJSON.sURLS,function(i) {
         imgList += "<a href='" + rJSON.sURLS[i] + "'><img class='hsImage' src='" + rJSON.iURLS[i] + "' /></a>";
     });
     page.find('.hsImages').html("<div class='imgListCont'>" + imgList + "</div>");
 };
```

This assumes `sURLS` and `iURLS` will always have the same number of items and that they are in the same order.